# Dogecoin daemon (dogecoind) returning "Method not found" error

Tags: dogecoin, node.js

I am trying to play with dogecoin deamon useing node-dogecoin library.

Unfortunately most calls I try return "Method not found" error

for example :

```
 dogecoin
.auth('MyUserName', 'mypassword')
.getNewAddress()
```

The only method I've managed to run successfully so far is :

```
.getmininginfo();
```

which makes me feel that deamon is working.

what could be the problem?

thanks.

Edit : debug.log file.

```
2015-02-16 05:47:57 GetNextWorkRequired() : RETARGET; target: 60, actual: 150, modulated: 71, before: 1b3b3a63, after: 1b461628
2015-02-16 05:47:57 UpdateTip: new best=7db9ae84010185d708f5f1236dd5102b5b4c904bb1099c388485721d2e5b449e  height=194311  log2_work=59.309095  tx=9406440  date=2014-04-24 07:24:42 progress=0.292254
2015-02-16 05:47:57 ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED
2015-02-16 05:47:57 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 152, prev=793c3f50e6725b056963fae977131f16b15b0d1b7e1c9c550fe8cec9a092f126
2015-02-16 05:47:57 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 153, prev=d54393112610200c1d47fb7ced2f9eb8d33f241fec209dfb2cc4502b462b5cb3
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 154, prev=3a2c422d3996c80bceef7e0a6901178ddf84d00c97d08990be63b4028e99abf7
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 155, prev=2dbaee58af92c0c92ea500bf88992c02ddddfb5ca7e3c2a1416b27c4f1b9cb9d
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 156, prev=9058c7d4c4439c074ffb58213a169ed524c142877230cb1823a637c468aec544
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 157, prev=012a8d8caa54c4115d05433390c060af3ed9d35f4761487bdf94a47aada02335
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 158, prev=0840f526c0828e6fe1dc9513dfd34acbf3bae8e8bbef719807d7f50180bf3c80
2015-02-16 05:47:58 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 159, prev=4b2ae3b0e5d79b8eb01146128ce98f608d42c450dca75aebe47d8ea072e144ff
2015-02-16 05:47:59 GetNextWorkRequired() : RETARGET; target: 60, actual: 29, modulated: 57, before: 1b461628, after: 1b42950c
2015-02-16 05:47:59 UpdateTip: new best=67981a7bdbbf610ce6bc35ac7065aadbb02c66bbfdb811a133692bc44731aec4  height=194312  log2_work=59.309103  tx=9406445  date=2014-04-24 07:24:56 progress=0.292254
2015-02-16 05:47:59 ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED
2015-02-16 05:47:59 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 160, prev=3872f8f2114d76d82fce03f96a9183f2e623627f0395b0166ecacd4bd604bc47
2015-02-16 05:47:59 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 161, prev=92f508ebcd8f8c5495d14cfbde46a82a6fd40ba00278b8f6d9547df1fb478e99
```

w.

Comment: Have you tried `getnewaddress` in lowercase?

Comment: @NickODell. Not sure if it is working ok but after building on another machine it stop throwing that error. On the other hand debug.log grows like crazy.

Comment: @wonglik can you provide relevant debug.log entries here?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie edited post and attached logs. My debug.log file within two minutes grows about 150kB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody has similar problem in the future. It seems that my dogecoind build was somehow incomplete. node-dogecoin was trying to call methods that were not available for some reasons. Building from scratch again solved the problem.

As for the log, it seems that it grows at the beginning but stabilize after a while.